# render_template is not redirecting to another page in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I am currently working on the below flask code. I'm trying to redirect to another HTML page using render_template but it's not working. However, I have tried to send back the JSON response to the AJAX at the client-side and by using the AJAX success response at the Client JavaScript code and by using the `window.location.href` functionality I am giving the URL of that HTML it's working.

But I need to use the render_template to redirect to another URL which actually fulfills my requirement. Please help me out.

```js
function myFunction() {

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ValidateOTP',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify($('#OTP').val()),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    success: function(response) {
      jsonvariable = response['success'].toString();
      if (jsonvariable == 'true')
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:63342/ElectricMan/templates/electricprofwelcomepage.html';

      else if (jsonvariable == 'false')
        document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "OTP didn't match !! Please click the GET OTP button to re-generate OTP";
      document.getElementById("div2").style.color = "Red";

    },
    error: function(response) {
      alert(response)

    }
  });
};
```

```
    @app.route('/ValidateOTP', methods=['GET','POST'])
def ValidateOTP():
    OTP = request.get_json()
    otpinstant=session['OTPINSTA']
    if otpinstant==OTP:
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        s = Session()
        query = s.query(ElectricMan).filter_by(email_id=email).first()
        result=query.first_name
        if result:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            #return render_template('electricprofwelcomepage.html')
            resp = jsonify(success=True)
            return resp

    else:
        resp = jsonify(success=False)
        return resp
```

Comment: Instead of `render_template` did you try with `return redirect(url_for("electricprofwelcomepage"))`

Comment: Not working i tried using url_for..its not working its showing a javascript pop up message "[object Object]"